# MomentJs время на 3 часа меньше приходит на почту

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Почему-то при выборе времени, в state записывается выбранное, потом при отправке на почту доходит ровно на 3 часа меньше.
`state: Thu May 30 2019 23:43:52 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)`
Почта:

[image: Данные с почты]

```js
class ValidationForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: "",
            lastname: "",
            date: null,
            time: null,
            email: "",
            mobile: "",
            age: "",
            complaints: "",
            doctor: ""
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeDate = this.handleChangeDate.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeTime = this.handleChangeTime.bind(this);
        this.submitEmail = this.submitEmail.bind(this);
    }


    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
        console.log(e.target.value)
    };
    handleChangeDate = date => {
        this.setState({date});

    };
    handleChangeTime = time => {
        this.setState({time},() => console.log(this.state.time));
    };
    DatePick = () => (
        <DatePicker placeholder="Дата приема" onChange={this.handleChangeDate}/>
    );
    TimePick = () => (
        <TimePicker  placeholder="Время приема" onChange={this.handleChangeTime} format={'HH:mm'}/>
    );

    async submitEmail() {
        const {
            username,
            lastname,
            date,
            time,
            email,
            mobile,
            age,
            complaints,
            doctor
        } = this.state;

        const form1 = await axios.post("/api/patient", {
            username,
            lastname,
            date,
            time,
            email,
            mobile,
            age,
            complaints,
            doctor
        });

    }

    render() {
        const {handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting} = this.props;
        return (
            <MDBContainer>
                <MDBRow className="flex-center">
                    <MDBCol md="6">
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submitEmail)} className="">
                            <span>
                                    Ваши данные для приема
                                </span>
                            <div className="">

                                <Field
                                    name="date"
                                    type="text"
                                    id="form3"
                                    component={this.DatePick}
                                />
                                <Field
                                    name="time"
                                    type="text"
                                    id="form4"
                                    component={this.TimePick}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button type="submit" disabled={submitting} className="btn btn-primary">
                                    Отправить ваши данные
                                </button>
                                <button
                                    type="button"
                                    disabled={pristine || submitting}
                                    onClick={reset}
                                >
                                    Clear Values
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </MDBCol>
                </MDBRow>
            </MDBContainer>

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: 3 часа - это разница между UTC и московским временем. Проверьте, в какой таймзоне работает сервер, куда приходят данные и который отправляет почту

Comment: Это одно и то же время. Смотрите в сторону отображения времени

Comment: А как оставить только время ,чтоб на почту приходило без даты ?Или добавлять просто 3 часа?